# Fastest way to compute distance between a point with an orientation to the boundaries of a region

Tags: matlab, image-processing, localization, grid, distance

I'm facing the following problem: I'm tracking a pixel that moves in a map. It has a position and an orientation. If its orientation is theta, I have the following angles to calculate the distance [theta-90 theta theta+90 theta+180], as the image shows for theta = 0 or theta = pi*n...

[image]

I calculated it in 2 ways:

```
x=[x , y, theta];
res=size(map)
v1= 1:res(1);
v2= 1:res(2);   
a_x=floor(x(1)+v1.*cos(x(3)*pi/180));  
a_y=floor(x(2)+v2.*sin(x(3)*pi/180));  
a=[a_x' a_y'];
```

first using the boundaries of the binary map

```
p=intersect(a,boundaries,'rows');
```

and using the binary map:

```
v=zeros(res(1),res(2));
a_x=a_x(a_x>=1 & a_x<=res(1));
a_y=a_y(a_y>=1 & a_y<=res(2));
a_x=a_x(1:min(length(a_y),length(a_x)));
a_y=a_y(1:min(length(a_y),length(a_x)));
v(sub2ind(size(v),a_x,a_y))=1;
p=find(v&map==1);
```

then calculated the shortest distance between the points and the boundaries with the two methods ...

```
x=repmat(x(1:2)',size(p,1),1);
d=min(sqrt((p(:,1)-x(:,1)).^2+(p(:,2)-x(:,2)).^2));
```

I'm doing it for a large image 1920x1080, however I do this for a lot of points with different orientations (2000 points) and it is slow. I would like to know if there's any alternative to compute this faster.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the distance transform? It's implemented as bwdist.m

Comment: I haven't tried, however I took a look and don't see how it can help me  (sorry if I am missing something) and since it will calculate the distance for all pixels it would probably take longer. thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: side note: this is wrong `x=[x , y, theta];`, `x` cannot be on both side with different dimensionalities.

Comment: My theta in the example in the code is just for one angle.I didn't include the rest of the code because it's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @StephenKowl You'll be surprised how fast is bwdist. It can precompute for you the nearest boundary pixel to each pixel in the image, which seems to be what you are doing. It is assumed that the boundary stays fixed throughout. Give it a try.